# How to configure VSTS Git repo in New VSTS Preview features?

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, devops, azure-pipelines

My "Build YAML Pipelines" are disabled.

But still I am not able to find VSTS repo to configure. It's showing/redirecting on GitHub Only.

Attached is the screen:[image]

Comment: If you turn off the preview feature Build YAML Pipelines, there should not show the the link to create YAML build. So could you share the screen shot for how you open the page you shared?

Comment: And you can follow up similar issue here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/322649/vsts-build-pipeline-creation-broken.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug then, but now it's been rectified and resolves. VSTS is working fine now